# Uneven floor and pending joints

Tags: flooring, ceiling, hardwood, joints

We found out after buying the house, when sanding the floors, that it’s uneven. We looked in basement to find out that there is wood pending between the joints.

Is this normal for house built in 1960?

We also noticed other cracks and nail pops all over the house, walls looking like it’s separated on ceiling ceiling and walls over the house. So disappointed for our first dream home.

What is that and is it normal we knew that the house had leaks but is was fixed by changing the roof.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What are those 2 small PCs between the joists?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! You've provided plenty of pics, but it's hard to identify what we're looking at in some of them. Please feel free to [edit] your post (I did so to fix the image embed for the first 3 images, then added spacing between the rest so we could tell that they're individual images) and add some descriptive text to tell us what we're looking at in each image. That will really help a lot!

Comment: Also, the "small PCs" between the joists are "blocking" they're there to help keep the joists from twisting. It's good for your floor.

Comment: Could not add any comments under the photos . 
First and second one is ( basement )underneath the uneven floor in my bedroom.

Comment: Were you sanding the floors, or did you hire someone to do it for you and they are handing you excuses? There is always a natural sag in the middle of floors were the bearing walls are on either end of a room. Some rooms, but not often have a beam under the floor in the  room, creating a high spot or hump. Your pics do not show anything out of sorts.

Comment: We did ourself. It’s not exactly in middle of the room it’s like little hump i can feel it when walking and I can hear the floors making sounds while walking on it

Comment: "pending" ... ? I don't think that means what you think it means ... [pending](https://www.google.com/search?q=pending+definition&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS840US840&oq=pending+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.7831j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) means unresolved or undecided - awaiting decision or settlement. I can't make any sense of what you're trying to describe here.

Comment: slanting;  lopsided . 
Was expecting  answer instead of making fun of spelling mistake